# Counterexample of Sobolev Embedding Theorem $W^{1,n}(\mathbb{R}^n) \nsubseteq L^\infty (\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I am looking for a counterexample of Sobolev Embedding Theorem $W^{1,n}(\mathbb{R}^n) \nsubseteq L^\infty (\mathbb{R}^n)$.

I feel that somehow the log(log()) function could provide an example but I am not figuring it out explicitly.

Comment: Indeed, try $\log\log\frac{1}{|x|}$ on the domain $0\leq |x|\leq \beta$ where $\beta<1$. It blows up at the origin so it’s not bounded, but with a change to polar coordinates it’s not terrible to show it’s in $W^{1,n}$.